# Populate custom List sub class from XML document via LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have figured out how to populate a custom class from XML data, but I ran into an issue along the way. Things were working perfectly with my existing method of populating data until I was thrown a bit of a curve ball. The new schema I was sent is similar to this:

```
<ITEM_REPLY>
<TRAN_ID>1320691307345</TRAN_ID>
<REPLY_CODE>0</REPLY_CODE>
<UNIT_PRICE>8.2784</UNIT_PRICE>
<SUP_LOCS>
  <SUP_LOC>
     <SUP_LOC_ID>001134</SUP_LOC_ID>
     <COUNTRY_ID>USA</COUNTRY_ID>
     <QTY_AVL>47.000</QTY_AVL>
     <ITEM_UOM>EA</ITEM_UOM>
  </SUP_LOC>
  <SUP_LOC>
     <SUP_LOC_ID>006817</SUP_LOC_ID>
     <COUNTRY_ID>USA</COUNTRY_ID>
     <QTY_AVL>20.000</QTY_AVL>
     <ITEM_UOM>EA</ITEM_UOM>
  </SUP_LOC>
</SUP_LOCS>
<MESSAGE />
<QTY_BREAKS />
</ITEM_REPLY>
```

Pretty standard XML schema, problem is I'm not sure how to populate my custom class with it. Here's what I do have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var order = ConvertXMLMessage<ItemReply>(request);
}

protected static T ConvertXMLMessage<T>(String xmlData) where T : class, new()
{
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(xmlData);

    var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (var xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(xml.DocumentElement))
    {
        T work = (T)(serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader));
        return work;
    }
}

public class ItemReply
{
    [XmlElement("ITEM_REPLY")]
    public ItemAvlReply ITEM_REPLY { get; set; }
}
public class ItemAvlReply
{
    [XmlElement("TRAN_ID")]
    public string TRAN_ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("REPLY_CODE")]
    public string REPLY_CODE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("UNIT_PRICE")]
    public string UNIT_PRICE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("SUP_LOCS")]
    public SupplierLocations SUP_LOCS;
    [XmlElement("MESSAGE")]
    public string MESSAGE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("QTY_BREAKS")]
    public string QTY_BREAKS { get; set; }
}
public class SupplierLocations
{
    [XmlElement("SUP_LOC")]
    public List<SupplierLocation> SUP_LOC;
}
public class SupplierLocation
{
    [XmlElement("SUP_LOC_ID")]
    public string SUP_LOC_ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("COUNTRY_ID")]
    public string COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("QTY_AVL")]
    public string QTY_AVL { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("ITEM_UOM")]
    public string ITEM_UOM { get; set; }
}
```

This works perfectly minus the `List<Item>` part. I'm not overly experienced with LINQ and I'm not sure how to go about declaring a sub array in my class via this statement. I am also open to a different approach from creating the `List<Item>` part, I'm just not sure where to start otherwise. Is there a better approach for what I'm need to do? Is there an easy solution I am just unaware of in LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it, assuming the example XML file you provided has typos. I assumed the OrderId has a closing tag, and that the closing tag for `Items` should be `/Items`.

Here's the version of the xml I used:

```
<Order>
<TransactionID>123</TransactionID>
<OrderID>1</OrderID>
<Items Number="2">
    <Item>
        <ItemName>Test</ItemName>
        <Color>Red</Color>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ItemName>Test1</ItemName>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
    </Item>
</Items>
</Order>
```

Here's the code to read/write the XML: (the xml variable is a String)

```
var order = ConvertXMLMessage<Order>(xml);
WriteXMLFile<Order>(order, @"test.xml");
```

Here's the ConvertXMLMessage and WriteXMLFile functions:

```
protected static T ConvertXMLMessage<T>(String xmlData) where T : class, new()
{
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(xmlData);

    var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (var xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(xml.DocumentElement))
    {
        T work = (T)(serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader));
        return work;
    }
}

protected static void WriteXMLFile<T>(T item, String saveLocation) where T : class, new()
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveLocation);
    writer.Serialize(file, item);
    file.Close();
}
```

and here's the class structure:

```
public class Order
{
    [XmlElement("TransactionID")]
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("OrderID")]
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Items")]
    public ItemsContainer Items;
}

public class ItemsContainer
{
    [XmlAttribute("Number")]
    public Int32 Number { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> Items;
}

public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("ItemName")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

As you'll notice I added some attributes to let the XML parser know how to handle the class when it's converting from/to the XML. I also added another small class called "ItemsContainer" just to hold the details on the Items tag. If you didn't need the "Number" attribute, then you could probably find a way to do away with this. However, this should get you in the right direction.

The example I provided is a simple version of how I usually handle the situation, obviously there's some improvements you can make depending on your needs.

**Edit**
I changed the Item class to use `ItemName` instead of `TransactionId`. It was an oversight on my part.

**Edit 2**
Here's the corrections you need to make to the newly posted code. The reason the `Order` class worked in the previous example was it matched the root XML element. You're new XML does align with the base class. So we need to add in a couple more attributes to make this work. You can also remove your `ItemReply` class. It's not needed.

So here's the new classes:

```
[XmlRoot("ITEM_REPLY")]
public class ItemAvlReply
{
    [XmlElement("TRAN_ID")]
    public string TRAN_ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("REPLY_CODE")]
    public string REPLY_CODE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("UNIT_PRICE")]
    public string UNIT_PRICE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("SUP_LOCS")]
    public SupplierLocations SUP_LOCS;
    [XmlElement("MESSAGE")]
    public string MESSAGE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("QTY_BREAKS")]
    public string QTY_BREAKS { get; set; }
}
public class SupplierLocations
{
    [XmlElement("SUP_LOC")]
    public List<SupplierLocation> SUP_LOC;
}
public class SupplierLocation
{
    [XmlElement("SUP_LOC_ID")]
    public string SUP_LOC_ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("COUNTRY_ID")]
    public string COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("QTY_AVL")]
    public string QTY_AVL { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("ITEM_UOM")]
    public string ITEM_UOM { get; set; }
}
```

Everything else should remain the same. The parsing/converting the XML to classes should work without any changes.

Comment: I am getting and error `There is an error in the XML document.`

Comment: Can you give me a bit more to go on? Are you using the XML I provided (I changed some pieces from the original because it looked like there was typos)? What .Net framework are you using? I've got the code above running in a test console job without any errors. I'm using .Net 4.5. If you're using the same framework and test XML then I'd need to see the code you implemented.

Comment: I'm going to fairly drastically change the above question. I posted a "dumbed" down xml and class definition just to get my point across. Give me a second and you can let me know if anything looks off.

Comment: It's updated. Here is the exact error as well `{System.InvalidOperationException: <ITEM_REPLY xmlns=''> was not expected.at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderItemReply.Read6_ItemReply()}`

Comment: I added an edit to the answer to fully explain the problem, but it boils down to the root XML tag doesn't match your class name.

Comment: Beautiful! If I could give you more thumbs up I would, Been racking my brain about this one for 2 days and looks like it's working now.