# Editing XML Output With LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq

I have an XML output file from a process being run that needs the contents of various fields edited according to a collection of tables in our database. For example, what's included in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfUserReportPreviewListDto xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UserReportPreviewListDto>
    <ExtensionData />
    <Id>previewReportFieldsId</Id>
    <Field0>-7</Field0>
    <Field1>L</Field1>
    <Field2>Lab Work Complete</Field2>
    <Field3>False</Field3>
    <Field4>LabWorkComplete</Field4>
    <Field6>False</Field6>
  </UserReportPreviewListDto>
  <UserReportPreviewListDto>
    <ExtensionData />
    <Id>previewReportFieldsId</Id>
    <Field0>-6</Field0>
    <Field1>S</Field1>
    <Field2>Sent to Lab</Field2>
    <Field3>False</Field3>
    <Field4>SentToLab</Field4>
    <Field6>False</Field6>
  </UserReportPreviewListDto>
  <UserReportPreviewListDto>
    <ExtensionData />
    <Id>previewReportFieldsId</Id>
    <Field0>-5</Field0>
    <Field1>V</Field1>
    <Field2>Void</Field2>
    <Field3>False</Field3>
    <Field4>Void</Field4>
    <Field6>True</Field6>
    <Field7>12/11/2013</Field7>
    <Field9>769</Field9>
  </UserReportPreviewListDto>
```

would need Field4 changed from LabWorkComplete (tblEnum.FieldTypeDesc) to 2 (tblEnum.FieldTypeNum).

I'm very new to using LINQ, and am not even completely sure it's the best route for this. I've created a DataSet in the project, with a DataTable populated from the database with what I need to work with. And...that's as far as I've got. Right now I'm using a massive list of tedious If statements to accomplish this, and am thinking this avenue may be more efficient than a collection of statements like this.

```
var xe = XElement.Load("serializer.xml");
string field4Value = xe.XPathSelectElement(@"/UserReportPreviewListDto/Field4").Value;
if (field4Value == "Incomplete")
{
    xe.XPathSelectElement(@"/UserReportPreviewListDto/Field4").Value = "0";
}
    else if (field4Value == "SendToLab")
{
xe.XPathSelectElement(@"/UserReportPreviewListDto/Field4").Value = "1";
}
    else if (field4Value == "LabWorkComplete")
{
    xe.XPathSelectElement(@"/UserReportPreviewListDto/Field4").Value = "2";
}
```

So that's where I am. If LINQ wouldn't be the best avenue, what would be? If it would be, what would be the best way to do it? Additionally, any particularly helpful resources along these lines that can be recommended would be appreciated; I'd much rather learn code than copy code. I'd hate to have to ask this again next week, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML structure is weird. `Field0...Field6` is not common, there are usually meaningful names in there. You can always write a function that encapsulates string to integer string conversion, and just provide an xpath as an argument. Then go higher level, provide xpath + conversion delegate, and from this point it's as easy as one line per property. Here is an implementation example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var xe = XElement.Load("serializer.xml");
      ConvertValue(xe, @"/UserReportPreviewListDto/Field4", TranslateValueField4);
    }

    private static void ConvertValue(XElement xe, string xpath, TranslateValue translator)
    {
      string field4Value = xe.XPathSelectElement(xpath).Value;
      xe.XPathSelectElement(xpath).Value = translator(field4Value);
    }

    private delegate string TranslateValue(string value);

    private static string TranslateValueField4(string value)
    {
      switch (value)
      {
        case "Incomplete" :
          return "0";
        case "SendToLab" :
          return "1";
        case "LabWorkComplete":
          return "2";
        default:
          throw new NotImplementedException(); //or provide handling for unknown values
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also avoid using xpath, and just iterate using foreach:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var doc = XDocument.Load(@"input.xml");
  foreach (var xe in doc.Root.Elements("UserReportPreviewListDto"))
  {
    ConvertValue(xe, "Field4", TranslateValueField4);
  }
  //doc.Save(path);
}

private static void ConvertValue(XElement xe, string fieldName, TranslateValue translator)
{
  //.Element returns Nothing if element is missing, may want to handle this case
  XElement field4 = xe.Element(fieldName);
  string field4Converted = TranslateValueField4(field4.Value);
  field4.SetValue(field4Converted);
}
```

Comment: It is weird, yeah. But it's provided to us from the client, so what can you do, eh?

Do you have a code example of what you're suggesting? I imagine it's not as complicated as it sounds, but seeing it written out would be a tremendous help.

Comment: is there a viable foreach statement I could use for multiple records in the XML file, to place beneath the delcaration of xe to cycle through the ConvertValue call? Is there any reason I wouldn't need to include one?

Comment: @Eiketsu: You may not even need xpath in your case. Assuming you have a list of `UserReportPreviewListDto` items under `ArrayOfUserReportPreviewListDto`, you could just iterate through the `Elements` collection of your document's root. This approach should be slightly faster.

Comment: The XPath route was a suggestion from a colleague, and something else I haven't worked with before. I'm grossly out of my range of experience at this point, but trying to stay afloat. It sounds simple, but it's not clicking for me. I don't suppose I can pester you for another bit of example, even after all you've done so far, can I?

Comment: @Eiketsu: Sure, not a problem, but first can I ask you to add a couple more items to your XML file (edit your question)? Just wanna make sure I understood the question.

Comment: @Eiketsu: Let's not bring the database in scope for now, until the rest is clear.

Comment: Hah! That looks like it did it. It's definitely given me a few new things to study. More than a few. Whew. But it is a great start for what I'll be working on moving forward as well. Thank you so much for your time and help with this. It's very appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I always, always, always prefect to store xml into custom classes and then work with them inside my C# environment. Makes the process of modifying it feel much more natural. Please look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784895/populate-custom-list-sub-class-from-xml-document-via-linq) to see the best way to do this. It takes a bit more time, but it makes things SO much easier in the long run. You said you wanted the best route and to learn, right? ;)

Comment: This approach never, never, never works in an enterprise setting. :) At some point you will need to resort to manual handling of all serialization. Especially if there are branches in serialization logic, i.e. if this, then field5 is an integer, and stored in propertyX, else if field6 is a date, then propertyY etc. Worse if processing depends on other fields, i.e. if field5 is this, then field6 is a path on disk, so you need to open a file, if field5 is that, than field6 is a path on FTP, you need credentials in field7 and field8.

Comment: It's a good approach, Volearix, and I appreciate the suggestion, but @Neolisk raises a good point. What this will eventually entail will changing things even further based on the main table of the reports this program will run. So what's Field4 in what I'm currently working on ("Type") may be something different in the next report ("CreationDate", for example). So that will add another level of complexity that it seems your system may have difficulty with (if I'm understanding it correctly). This is one more reason I think LINQ may be the way to go, but still don't know for certain.